# JQuery text function returns repeated text. Why?

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of html:

```
<div class="participant inline_part" data-part-id="37aaae8">
    [...]
    <div class="member_1 inline_member">
        [...]
        <span class="member_name"><a class="aLink" href="/user/15">Bob Moidusen</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="member_2 inline_member">
        [...]
        <span class="member_name">Mark Sidhuescu</span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

If I call:

```
$("div[data-xct-part-id='37aaae8'] div.member_1 .member_name").text();
```

and

```
$("div[data-xct-part-id='37aaae8'] div.member_2 .member_name").text();
```

**It returns me "Bob MoidusenBob Moidusen" and "Mark SidhuescuMark Sidhuescu".**

Why?

[EDITED] I have the same problem with succesive calls to find:

```
$("div[data-xct-part-id='37aaae8']").find("div.member_2").find(".member_name").text();
```

I'd like to understand this in order to avoid future similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two elements that matched the selection. So, acording to `text()` specifications (*Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.*), the text was returned twice.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that it does not do this.

I have put your example up in a fiddle (and fixed search query, removing the "xct"):

http://jsfiddle.net/jppresents/jy5jrd2s/

```
console.log('Result query 1:' + $("div[data-part-id='37aaae8'] div.member_1 .member_name").text());
console.log('Result query 2: ' + $("div[data-part-id='37aaae8'] div.member_2 .member_name").text());
```

Results in this output in the console:

```
Result query 1:Bob Moidusen
Result query 2: Mark Sidhuescu
```

At least when using jquery 1.11.0 as shown in the linked fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've seen that if html schema is duplicated the text is returned twice. I thought that text() returned the text of the first element in jquery object but seems that concatenated text is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Change your calls to

```
$("div[data-xct-part-id='37aaae8'] div.member_1 > .member_name").text();
$("div[data-xct-part-id='37aaae8'] div.member_2 > .member_name").text();
```

That should solve your problem.

As to WHY it's doing it, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` in jquery

```
var res = $(".inline_member span.member_name").map(function() {

         return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(res);
```

or

```
$("div.member_1 .member_name").text()
$("div.member_2 .member_name").text()
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5b8shk1/)